# Apache2 locations: deny root, allow path

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have a configuration where I wish to block users accessing the root

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName foo.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www

  <Location "/">
    Require all denied
  </Location>

  <Location "/bar">
    Require all granted
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

If I change the first path to `/bar` and second to `/bar/baz` this works (`/bar` is blocked, `/bar/baz` is allowed) but reducing it to the root does not have the intended effect - both `/`, `/bar` and indeed any path for "foo.com" get denied.

What can I do to allow this structure, where only a specific domain with a specific path works, everything else is denied (or errors, or otherwise doesn't work for the client)

Notes: This is for Apache 2.4, and for `Location` rather than `Directory` (as the application it's pointing at uses a fixed index and mod_rewrite to pass paths to a router)

Comment: you can have two `VirtualHost` different server name, remove the location for "/" and only define sub directory alone refer this https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#location

Comment: I did try using two VirtualHosts however I don't have a server name for the one with / denied, and wasn't able to get the configuration to work. Sadly the docs don't have an example for this case. If you'd care to have a go at an example I'd be interested to try it out!

Comment: you add the hostname in the hosts file and map it to 127.0.0.1, let me gat an example for you

Answer (score 1):

I have introduced these entries in `hosts` file

```
127.0.0.1 www.daffyduck.com
127.0.0.1 www.tomandjerry.com
```

Then I put these configuration

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  DocumentRoot "C:/MyFiles/xampp/htdocs/tomandjerry"
  ServerName www.tomandjerry.com:443
  <Location "/">
    Require all denied
  </Location>
  <LocationMatch "(/bar1.*|/bar1/.*)">
    Require all granted
  </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  DocumentRoot "C:/MyFiles/xampp/htdocs/daffyduck"
  ServerName www.daffyduck.com:443
  <Location "/">
    Require all denied
  </Location>
  <LocationMatch "(/bar2.*|/bar2/.*)">
    Require all granted
  </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

If I type `https://www.daffyduck.com/` I get `You don't have permission to access this resource.` If I put `https://www.daffyduck.com/bar2/` then I get the index.html

Comment: Thanks, I don't get what the hosts file is doing here, or is that example just for local testing? I don't need to worry about that but otherwise your format seems similar to mine other than using location match - could that be the difference?

Comment: hosts file is simply for local testing, locationmatch allows regular expression, otherwise it will same as yours

Comment: Right OK; but mine doesn't work, so I'm struggling to see what difference your answer is to mine?